# Ignore specific attribute/fields in jsonassert

Tags: java, jsonassert

I need to compare two json strings by ignore some fields

I am currently using JSONAssert from org.SkyScreamer to do the comparison but does not ignore any attributes.

Json 1 :

```
{
  "contributions": [
    [
      {
        "order" : 1,
        "contributorId" : "1980"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Json 2 :

```
{
  "contributions": [
    [
      {
        "order": 1,
        "contributorId" : "5789"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

```
ArrayValueMatcher<Object> arrValMatch1 = new ArrayValueMatcher<>(new CustomComparator(
                JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE,
                new Customization("contributions[0][*].contributorId",(o1, o2) -> true)));

        Customization arrayValueMatchCustomization = new Customization("contributions", arrValMatch1);
        CustomComparator customArrayValueComparator = new CustomComparator(
                JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE,
                arrayValueMatchCustomization);
       assertEquals(subJson1, json2, customArrayValueComparator);
```

I expect the above scenario should be passed. But its failing with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: contributions[0][contributorId=1980]
Expected: a JSON object
     but none found
 ; contributions[0][contributorId=5789]
Unexpected: a JSON object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `*.contributorId` instead of `contributions[0][*].contributorId`